# MySQL data summary tricks - is there an UNGROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to do some data reporting, and don't do SQL gymnastics often enough to know what feature I'm looking for.  I'd call it an "ungroup by".  I have a SELECT outputting this, reflecting a series of monthly subscription items: when they were created, closed, and how much the monthly spend is:

```
+----+---------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | description                     | created_on | closed_on  | monthly    |
+----+---------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 | Daily horoscope email           | 2012-01-01 | null       | 10000.0000 |
|  5 | Pet food delivery               | 2012-01-05 | null       |  3500.0000 |
|  6 | Dirty magazine subscription     | 2012-01-09 | null       |  1500.0000 |
|  7 | Stupid nuts posted in a box     | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-04 |  1500.0000 |
  .... etc ...
```

What I'm trying to do is work out the "run rate" on a daily basis.  So every day is listed, with a running total of the current monthly commitment, i.e. the above data would map to:

```
+------------+----------+
| date       | run_rate |
+------------+----------+
| 2012-01-01 | 11500    |
| 2012-01-02 | 11500    |
| 2012-01-03 | 11500    |
| 2012-01-04 | 10000    |
| 2012-01-05 | 13500    |
| 2012-01-06 | 13500    |
| 2012-01-07 | 13500    |
| 2012-01-08 | 13500    |
| 2012-01-09 | 15000    |
```

What I thought might be possible is to create a temporary table with one row for every day, then write a LEFT JOIN / GROUP BY statement referencing the first table to build my output.  But I can only see how to create a day-by-day "difference" that way, not a running total, and I'd need to "ungroup" the first table into two entries, a positive entry for when the subscription is created, and a negative entry for when it's closed.

I'd like to stick to MySQL, and if possible, in one mega-statement.  If that's not possible I can add some stored procedures or temporary tables to my query framework.  Or do I really have to grind my data through Ruby?  (I know exactly how, but was hoping I could keep all my logic in one place, and I'm trying to improve on our current slow calculation that uses ActiveRecord).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` where it will create a date within and without having to create a temp table. `Explan plan` can confirm you which method would be best suitable for you.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58af/2)

SET @rrate:=0;

```
SELECT X.rdate, (@rrate:=@rrate +
COALESCE(Y.summonthly,0) -
COALESCE(Z.summonthly,0)) as run_rate
FROM(
      SELECT date_add(P.createdon, interval `day` day)
      as rdate
      FROM 
          (SELECT @i:= @i + 1 AS `day`
           FROM   
           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY,
           (SELECT @i:= -1) AS i
           ) As D,
      rategroups P
      GROUP BY rdate
      HAVING rdate <= (SELECT MAX(createdon) FROM rategroups)
      ORDER BY rdate) X
LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT createdon, sum(monthly) summonthly
       FROM rategroups
       GROUP BY createdon) Y
ON X.rdate = Y.createdon
LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT closed_on, sum(monthly) summonthly
       FROM rategroups
       GROUP BY closed_on) Z
ON X.rdate = Z.closed_on
GROUP BY X.rdate
;

|                          RDATE | RUN_RATE |
---------------------------------------------
| January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    11500 |
| January, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    11500 |
| January, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    11500 |
| January, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    10000 |
| January, 05 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    13500 |
| January, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    13500 |
| January, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    13500 |
| January, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    13500 |
| January, 09 2012 00:00:00+0000 |    15000 |
```

Comment: @MatthewBloch in this method you do not have to create a temp table. It's being created within and you may provide the max date from your table as the end date to complete the dates between. :) Please comment after trying out and also don't forget to look into the `Explain Plan`

Comment: I like that method of generating a date table, though the table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA only has 130 rows.  But you do make the point that as long as I can lay my hands on _any_ table with the number of rows I want, I can generate another one with a sequence.  Which was the bit of the puzzle I was stuck with.  Will just double-check it all works and see how fast it goes.

Comment: Oh I am quite liking `set @i=0; select date_add(now(), interval (select @i := @i+1) day) from big_table limit 100;` for generating my date sequence.  If it's going to be vile, it can at least be short :)

Comment: Most important thing, how fast for a larger table =) I am glad you got it worked out. And BTW check this out for [rows `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.collation_character_set_applicability` can generate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58af/3) -> 197 :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -- should produce your desired results:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT
   mydates.seeddate,
    (@runtot := @runtot + IFNULL(m.amt,0) - IFNULL(m2.amt,0)) AS rt
FROM
   mydates left join 
    (Select createdon, SUM(monthly) amt
     FROM mytable 
     group by createdon
     ) m on mydates.seeddate = m.createdon
left join 
    (Select closed_on, SUM(monthly) amt
     FROM mytable 
     group by closed_on  
     ) m2 on mydates.seeddate = m2.closed_on
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd984/2).

Good luck.

Comment: That running total logic is very clear, thanks.  I am struggling to generate the dates table on-the-fly, but @bonCodigo seems to have that covered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select date,sum(monthly)
from     
(
   select created_on as date from yourtable 
   union 
   select closed_on from yourtable where closed_on is not null
) as alldates
left outer join yourtable
  on date >= created_on
 and (closed_on is null or date < closed_on)
where date between '2012-1-1' and '2012-1-31'
group by date order by 1
```

According to your example data,the output is :

```
+------------+--------------+
| date       | sum(monthly) |
+------------+--------------+
| 2012-01-01 |     11500.00 |
| 2012-01-04 |     10000.00 |
| 2012-01-05 |     13500.00 |
| 2012-01-09 |     15000.00 |
+------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can figure that date of the day not out there equals to the nearest one.Say, run_rate of '2012-01-02' equals run_rate of '2012-01-01'.

Suppose you already have a table which contains all dates of the month,we call it "mydate", with one column "date".

```
mysql> select * from mydate where date >= '2012-1-1' and date <= '2012-1-31';
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2012-01-01 |
| 2012-01-02 |
| 2012-01-03 |
| 2012-01-04 |
| 2012-01-05 |
| 2012-01-06 |
| 2012-01-07 |
...
```

Then replace

```
(
select created_on as date from yourtable 
union 
select closed_on from yourtable where closed_on is not null
) as alldates
```

with `mydate`

Done!

Comment: Cunning use of the existing table to generate the date list, but I'm pretty sure that a union of both date columns won't cover every possible date.  It will cover every date that something happened on of course, but the graphing layer has to do more work there that I'm trying to avoid!